# How can I update slug automatic when I will be changed name with slugify mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

The product's slug is created when I post a product. But the slug did not update when I changed the product name.

Here is my code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { default: slugify } = require('slugify');

const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      unique: true,
      required: [true, 'Please add product name'],
    },
    slug: String,

    sku: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: [true, 'Please add product sku'],
    },

    isActive: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
    },
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
  }
);

ProductSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  this.slug = slugify(this.name, { lower: true });
  next();
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Prduct', ProductSchema );
```

I want to update  the slug automatically when the name is changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [virtuals](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html) for this. Delete the property on the schema and use this instead:

```
ProductSchema.virtual('slug').get(function() {
  return slugify(this.name, { lower: true });
});
```

The property will not actually exist in the database and will be dynamically determined based on whatever the current name is.

Comment: How can I get data by the virtual property?

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to utilize the `slugify` module with `mongoose.pre('save')` middleware like so.

E.g.

```bash
// someModel.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const slug = require('slugify');

const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      unique: true,
      required: [true, 'Please add product name'],
    },
    slug: String,

    ...
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
  }
);

ProductSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
  const product = this

  if (!product.isModified('name')) return next()

  const slug = slugify(product.name, { lower: true, trim: true })

  product.slug = slug

  return next()
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Prduct', ProductSchema );

// someController.js

const updateProduct = async (req, res) => {
    const { productId } = req.params
    
    const { name, ... } = req.body
    
    try {
        // const product = await Product.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, { new: true }) not working instead:
    
    let product = await Product.findById(productId)

    product?.name = name
    ...

    await product.save()
    
    return res.status(200).json(product)
        
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message)
      }
  }
```